# Ubuntu - Using multimedia keys while screen is locked

Tags: ubuntu

When system screen is locked one have to provide password before doing anything else.

However, I would like to use my keyboard's multimedia keys (e.g. change volume up and down) without typing the password first. How can I achieve this?

System is Ubuntu 10.04, quite default setup. Multimedia keys work flawlessly when the screen is not locked.

Comment: I'ts been two years - Was this ever put into a release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that is possible with the current screensavers, by design.